# Receing null on activeuser after signing is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using local storage to store username and password
I am getting null on active user after this line of code, I dont know why

```
 console.log("I am the Active user: " + activeUser);
```

```
const menuChannelIcon = $(".menu-channel-icon");
const bellIcon = $(".bell-btn");
const uploadButtonIcon = $(".upload-btn");
const signInMainPageIcon = $(".signInMainPage");
const signUpMainPageIcon = $(".signUpMainPage");
const signOutMainPageIcon = $(".signOutMainPage");
const videoSectionMainPage = $(".video-section");

const signin = () => {
  console.log("signin button clicked")
  if (localStorage.getItem("formData")) {
    // as long as you are getting items from the local storage... do..
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")).forEach((data) => {

      let x = $("#signEmail").val();
      let z = $("#signinPassword").val();

      if (data.email == x && data.pwd == z) {
        isLogged = true;
        activeUser = localStorage.getItem(email);
        console.log("I am the Active user: " + activeUser);

        menuChannelIcon.show();
        bellIcon.show();
        uploadButtonIcon.show();
        signInMainPageIcon.hide();
        signUpMainPageIcon.hide();
        signOutMainPageIcon.show();
        singIn_formContainer.hide();
        videoSectionMainPage.show();
        console.log("You are LOGGED");
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Edit: email and pwd are set during signup

Comment: You never set the `email` variable.

Comment: where are you setting the data in local storage?

Comment: Maybe that should be quoted? `localStorage.getItem("email")`

Comment: Shouldn't the active user be `x` when the email and password match something from `formData`? Why are you getting the active user from local storage?

Comment: You should use the `find()` function instead of a `forEach()` loop, so that it stops when it finds the matching item.

Comment: Good catch @Barmar 

Thank you, your suggestion fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted by Barmar in the comments:
localStorage.getItem("email")

Alternative answer:
Shouldn't the active user be x when the email and password match something from formData? Why are you getting the active user from local storage?